# Flatness and Cohen-Macaulay rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an Artin local ring and let $f:A \to B$  a local ring homomorphism to  a Noetherian local one dimensional $A$-algebra $B$.

> If $B$ is Cohen--Macaulay and the localization of $B$ at any minimal prime is flat over $A$, then is $B$ flat over $A$?

As far as I can see, this doesn't follow from any of the standard flatness criteria, but I could have missed something simple.

(I am mostly interested in the case that $B$ is the localization of a finite type $A$-algebra at some maximal ideal, but it seems likely that the answer to the question is the same with or without this extra assumption.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not true.  Let $k$ be a field.  A module over the ring of dual numbers, $A=k[\epsilon]/\langle \epsilon^2 \rangle,$ is equivalent to a $k$-vector space $B$ with a square-zero $k$-linear self-map $L_\epsilon:B\to B.$ For every integer $q\geq 1$, the Tor module equals, $$\text{Tor}^A_{q\geq 1}(A/\langle \overline{\epsilon}\rangle,B) = H(L_\epsilon,B) = \text{Ker}(L_\epsilon)/\text{Image}(L_\epsilon).$$ Now let $B$ be the following one-dimensional, local, Noetherian $k$-algebra that is a local complete intersection, hence Cohen-Macaulay, $$B=k[x,y]_{\langle x,y \rangle}/ \langle y^2\rangle,$$ where $L_\epsilon$ is multiplication by $\overline{xy}.$

The localization of $B$ at the unique minimal prime $\mathfrak{p}=\langle \overline{y}\rangle$ is $$B_\mathfrak{p} = k(x)[y]/\langle y^2\rangle.$$  The homology module for this localization is $$H(L_\epsilon,B_{\mathfrak{p}}) = \{0\}.$$ Thus, $B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is $A$-flat.  However, $B$ is not flat since $\text{Tor}_{q\geq 1}^A(B,A/\mathfrak{m})$ equals
$$ \text{Ker}(L_{\overline{xy}}:k[x,y]/\langle y^2\rangle \to k[x,y]/\langle y^2\rangle)/\text{Image}(L_{\overline{xy}}:k[x,y]/\langle y^2\rangle \to k[x,y]/\langle y^2\rangle) = $$ $$\langle \overline{y}\rangle / \langle \overline{xy} \rangle = k\cdot \overline{y},$$ which is one-dimensional.

Comment: In the definition of $B$, do you mean the quotient by $y^2$?

Comment: @Sasha  Yes, that was a typo.  Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Thanks! Do you think that there can be a counterexample which has a reduced special fibre? This would suffice for my application (to justify the inclusion on l. 3 of p.12 of this [paper](http://www.math.brown.edu/~bhassett/papers/K3infinitecurves/rankone10.pdf)).

Comment: @ulrich.  I do not know whether or not the result is true after imposing a reducedness hypothesis for $B/\mathfrak{m}_A B.$  The result appears to be true if $B/\mathfrak{m}_A B$ is regular.  The same argument might apply if $B/\mathfrak{m}_A B$ is a local complete intersection scheme, e.g., the domain curve of a stable map.

Comment: @JasonStarr: OK, thanks a lot! I will think some more about the lci case.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Suppose $R$ is a reduced one dimensional local ring over a field $k$ which is not regular, and let $R'$ be its normalization (assumed to be finite). We can then make $R \oplus R'$ into a $k[\epsilon]$ algebra: the multiplication is that of the "square zero extension" of $R$ by $R'$ (viewed simply as an $R$-module) and $\epsilon$ acts by $\epsilon(r,r') = (0,\epsilon r)$. This is CM and flat at the generic points but not flat over $k[\epsilon]$. (So it seems that for the application to BHT one must use that $\mathrm{embdim}(B) \leq \mathrm{embdim}(A) + 2$.)

Comment: @ulrich  I believe that the $k$-algebra you describe is not Cohen-Macaulay.  Let $r'\in R'$ be an element in the relative complement $R'\setminus R.$  For the corresponding element $(0,r'),$ the annihilator ideal $I$ of this element of $R\oplus R'$ contains $\{0\}\oplus R'$. However, the quotient ideal $I/\{0\}\oplus R'$, as an ideal in $R\oplus R'/(\{0\}\oplus R') \cong R,$ contains a nonzero proper ideal of $R,$ since $R'\otimes_R \text{Frac}(R)$ equals $\text{Frac}(R)$.  Thus, for a maximal annihilator ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ containing $I$, $\mathfrak{q}$ is an embedded prime of $R\oplus R'.$

Comment: @JasonStarr: I am not sure about the second to last sentence in your comment: $(x,0) \cdot (0, r') = (0, xr')$ and if $x, r'$ are both non-zero then $xr'$ is non-zero (since $R$ injects into $R'$ and $R'$ is reduced; one could assume that both rings are integral domains). (I noticed a mistake in the definition of $\epsilon$: one should simply take $\epsilon = (0,1)$.)

Comment: You are correct. I did the computation too quickly.